# How can chia seeds be added to cookie dough without affecting the spread?

Tags: cookies, chia

I’d like to add chia seeds to oatmeal cookies, but I know they can act as a binding agent, which I don’t want.

I’ve heard you should soak them first, but that adds liquid, which would also affect the recipe.

What is the best way to compensate for the chia seeds so the end result is very similar in spread, texture, and flavor?

Comment: What do you expect/want the texture of the chia seeds themselves to be in the final cookies?